# How to Write a Short Story Collection?

Tags: publishing, short-story

I plan on writing a collection of short stories. How should the manuscript be formatted? Can I write new short stories specifically for the collection. How hard is it to get published (I need someone to answer who has experience with this) I plan on writing a collection of short stories about a Venus where the tropes of the 1950's are its reality.

Comment: I'm afraid there are too many questions here, most of which do not have an absolute answer. I suggest that if you want to write short stories you should do so. Once they are written some of the other questions may be able to be answered.

Comment: As S Mitchell said, there are multiple questions here. On a Q/A site you need to ask one question at a time. But ask yourself this: In a bookstore, how many short story collections do you find, other than the occasional anthology? And if you do find a short story collection, is it by an unknown author?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the manuscript format just yet. Write your stories. Edit your stories. Try to get your stories published in journals. Then pull your stories together for a collection.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simillar problem with my Superhero novels I'm working.  Typically I tend to format them like a television show.  The main characters are constant and the problem of the chapter is largely introduced and resolved in the course of the "chapter".  I used this format after being a fan of the Encyclepedia Brown series, which typically had a predictable format of short mysteries (The first chapter was always solving a case for his police chief father's work load that was stumping the detectives, followed by one introducing the Lemondae-Style Detective Agency Brown ran and his nemesis Bugs Meany, a few unrelated cases (late in the series, the third chapter featured Bugs trying to get revenge (not always related to the previous chapter) by Framing Brown) and a recurring chapter about foiling the local kid conartist.).

I say largely becuase my chapters do have a bit of continuity in them that will influence the last few chapters, but I'm adicted to villains who are playing the long game.  To this regard, I think of it as an episodic television series... your setting is the same, but your stories are contained to a chapter a piece.  Can't say with publishing as I'm still on the "write it" part, but given that there are products that exist in roughly that format, I can't see a problem.

Would these formats be slice of life (Life on Venus... chapter one deals with government intrique, chapter two deals with a "typical" house wife, and so on) or is there a set plot to all the short stories?  Mostly for formatting the correct order.